# Cypress 11.2.0 How to clear configuration?

Tags: configuration, cypress

I have already installed cypress. With the command `cypress open` the app is opening. The app shows a not existing configuration.
The shown config is a old, but removed from root.

Questions:

1. Where come from this configuration?
2. How to remove it? (there is no button...)

[image]

Comment: Try clearing the Cypress App Data -> https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/troubleshooting#To-clear-App-Data